# How to read a file between two delimiters and save the contents to a String array

Tags: java, string, file, extract

I'm working on a project which requires me to read Java files within my Java code. I am only interested in extracting the contents of the `main` within said file. My initial idea was to detect the `main` keyword and read until I found `}` but I haven't been able to put it in place.

What I am reading will always have the following form:

```
package abc;
public class something {
    public static main void(String[] args) {
        //The information I want to save
    }
}
```

I've noticed there is a major recommendation to use the Scanner to do this, but I'm failing to see how to do so correctly and efficiently.

Comment: A Java code parser is more appropriate IMO

Comment: I would agree but I have to explicitly have the parsing within my code in the end and I'm not sure writing a parser within my code wouyld be efficient nor effective

Comment: So it'a a homework

Comment: Searching for a `}` will give you the wrong answer for various reasons including nested blocks and `}` characters in string literals and comments.  Similarly, trhe first "main" you find may not be the method name for the `public static void main(String[])` method.

Comment: You don't need to *write* a parser.  You could generate one, or use an existing parser library that produces an in-memory AST.

Comment: _"I've noticed there is a major recommendation to use the Scanner to do this"_, where did you get that recommendation? Because it is not a good one for parsing source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to read a file between two delimiters and save the contents to a String array

The simple way to implement that would be:

1. Read entire file contents to a string.
2. Use a pattern to extract the string you want; e.g. something like this

   ```
      String contents = ...
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\wmain\\w([^}]*)}",
                                  Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
      if (m.find()) {
          String matched = m.group(1);
          ...
      } else {
          ...
      }
   ```

   (This is intended to be purely illustrative of the *approach* ... not a working solution.)

I should warn you that this approach will be NOT be reliable.

1. Searching for the word `main` will pick up all sorts of other occurrences of the word; e.g. in comments, string literals, variable names and so on.
2. Searching for the character `}` will pick up the character in comments and literals.
3. The first `}` after `main` could be the end of a nested block in the main method.

The correct way to do this is to implement a JAVA parser.

---

> I've noticed there is a major recommendation to use the Scanner to do this.

That recommendation is wrong. `Scanner` offers nothing that will help in solving this problem.

---

You said that you don't think it is worth the effort of writing a Java parser.  You don't need to *write* a parser. You could generate one, or use an existing parser library that produces an in-memory AST.

But I guess, if this code only needs to work for a strictly controlled set of inputs, it might be viable.  For example, if the source code `main` method never has blocks inside the `main` method block.

Finally, you have not said why you are doing this.  Depending on what you are going to do with the extracted source code fragment, you may be able to implement this a different way.  For example, you might be able to BCEL or similarly to find and pick apart the `main` method at the bytecode level.

Comment: Thank you very much! I acknowledge the fact that this way of functioning isn't the best but in terms of what I wanted to know, this is excatly that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExp {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String code = "package abc;"                                      + "\n"
                +           ""                                                  + "\n"
                +           "public class something {"                          + "\n"
                +           ""                                                  + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "public static void moth(String[] args) {" + "\n"
                +           "\t\t" +     "/* some code */"                      + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "}"                                        + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "public static void main(String[] args) {" + "\n"
                +           "\t\t" +     "/* some code */"                      + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "}"                                        + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "public static void meth(String[] args) {" + "\n"
                +           "\t\t" +     "/* some code */"                      + "\n"
                +           "\t"   + "}"                                        + "\n"
                +           "}"                                                 + "\n"
                ;

        System.out.println(code);

        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s(main\\s*\\(.+?})", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(code);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

But, as has been noted elsewhere, this will only find the most trivially simple main Methods.